# Parallax effect issue using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to achieving a parallax effect using JavaScript.

I have a primary header in which its height is determined by the height of the browser to make it full height. I then want to push down the secondary header by however much the height is of the primary header.

This is what I have so far:

```
var primaryHeader = document.getElementById('primary-header');
var secondaryHeader = document.getElementById('secondary-header');
primaryHeader.style.height = (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) - 40 + 'px';
secondaryHeader.style.marginTop = primaryHeader + 40 + 'px';

window.onresize = function() {
    primaryHeader.style.height = (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) - 40 + 'px';
    secondaryHeader.style.marginTop = primaryHeader + 40 + 'px';
};
```

When I try to apply the margin to the secondary header it does not seem to work. Am I doing anything fundamentally wrong?

Here is an example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d79TT/

Thanks.

Comment: Could you put it all in a Fiddle?

Comment: We need a lot more info to diagnose.  Please provide CSS and HTML markup as well and replicate the issue in a JSFiddle if possible.

Comment: @lucasnadalutti http://jsfiddle.net/d79TT/

Comment: @Ennui Sorry. I've now included this fiddle as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/d79TT/

Comment: What is `widows: 100%` supposed to be doing?

Comment: @AlexW haaah I was just about to ask that. Faooful I'm a bit confused about what you are trying to accomplish here, would you mind trying to explain a little more clearly what you want to happen?

Comment: You may want to include an image of "expected results" for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The widows: 100% is an error I do apologies. What I'm trying to achieve is whent he user scrolls the secondary-header slides above the primary header. However my main issue is why my JavaScript as I want the primary-header to start off as 100% height of the browser and then the secondary header to take the primary-headers height and use that as margin-top. Is this a little more clear? I don't mean to be so cryptic. :(

Comment: If you want two elements to be 100% of the browser's height, you don't need JS. Just set the height of both sibling elements to 100%. Or you can give your second element 100% top margin and then you've got no need to re-calculate the position when the page loads or when the browser resizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
secondaryHeader.style.marginTop = primaryHeader.style.height + 40 + 'px';
```

You are doing string concatenation, instead of addition.

Because `primaryHeader.style.height` returns something like `172px`, which is a string, so the end result would be:

```
172px40px
```

instead of

```
212px
```

Comment: What would be the correct way to use primary-headers height as the margin for secondary-header?

Comment: I've got it so it now uses the height using secondaryHeader.style.marginTop = primaryHeader.style.height; How do I add 40px to the primaryHeader.style?

Comment: Try this: `secondaryHeader.style.marginTop = (parseInt(primaryHeader.style.height) + 40) + "px";`